# how to combine \parentext with \headlesscite to make \pheadlesscite

Tags: macros, biblatex-chicago

Using `biblatex-chicago`/`biber`, how can I create a new command `\pheadlesscite` such that `\pheadlesscite[20]{citekey}` has the same result as `\parentext{\headlesscite[20]{citekey}}`?

I imagine the solution would use `\newrobustcmd`, but I haven't figured out how.

Comment: Please add an compilable code and two relevant bib entrys to your question ...

Comment: oops, sorry, I just realized this command already exists; it's called `\headlessparencite`.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a command combining those commands, so my question was even more elementary than I thought. The answer (answering the spirit, not the letter of my question) is: `\headlessparencite[20]{citekey}`.